# package.skeleton cxxfunction and R functions

Tags: r, rcpp

I read Rcpp frequently asked questions and found how to build a function with my inline prototype like

```
fun <- cxxfunction(...)
```

making

```
package.skeleton("mypackage", fun)
```

it worked perfectly, but, when I tried to mix normal R functions with cxxfunctions it did not work. Any guess? 
There is at least a way to add codes to an existing skeleton?

Comment: Have you looked at [http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-package.pdf](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-package.pdf] or [https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Rcpp](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Rcpp)?

Comment: Hi, I've solved the problem editing the NAMESPACE file, putting my code inside R folder and compiling again. But I had not seen this part of devtools wiki, thank you.